# Room: Not able to start activity adding the ID to the intent

Tags: java, android, android-room

This is my main activity. I have a list consisting members. I want to click on a customer and start the MemberInfo activity.

```
public class MemberMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MemberListAdapter.MemberClickListener{

private MemberViewModel mMemberViewModel;
private List<Member> mMember;

void setMember(List<Member> members) {
    mMember = members;
}

public static final int NEW_MEMBER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_member);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MemberMainActivity.this, NewMemberActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_MEMBER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewcard_member);
    final MemberListAdapter adapter = new MemberListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mMemberViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MemberViewModel.class);

    mMemberViewModel.getAllMember().observe(this, new Observer<List<Member>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Member> members) {
            mMember = members;
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            adapter.setMember(members);
        }
    });

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == NEW_MEMBER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Member member = new Member(data.getStringExtra(NewMemberActivity.EXTRA_REPLY), data.getStringExtra(NewMemberActivity.EXTRA_REPLY2));
        mMemberViewModel.insert(member);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


public void onMemberClick(int position) {
    Log.i("what", "gotpositionroger");
        Member member = mMember.get(position);
        Log.i("the", "aftergotpositionroger");
        MemberInfo.open(this, member.getId());
  }
}
```

This is my MemberInfo activity.

```
public class MemberInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

public static void open(Activity activity, long memberid) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MemberInfo.class);
    intent.putExtra("MemberID", memberid);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_memberinfo);

    -------------Log.i("okay", "memberinfo");---------------
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("MemberID")) {
        long memberid = intent.getLongExtra("MemberID", -1);
        // TODO: get customer details based on customer id
        intent.putExtra("MemberID", memberid);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.empty_not_saved,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is: When I click on a member, it's just loading and loading and after some seconds, the app crashes.

In my MemberInfo activity, I marked a line with a Log.i. When I click on a member, the logcat shows me the same Log.i again and again - The Log.i gets repeated infinitely.

After my app crashes, the logcat shows this:

> 06-18 19:36:33.662 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   E/GraphicBuffer: unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Unknown error -2
>   (2)
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.662 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung E/Surface:
>   dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: 2
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.662 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   E/EGL_emulation: tid 5070: swapBuffers(550): error 0x300d
>   (EGL_BAD_SURFACE)
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.662 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: swapBuffers encountered EGL error 12301 on
>   0x942b8a20, halting rendering...
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.663 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa33983c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo
>   0xa322a560)
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.729 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   E/gralloc_ranchu: map_buffer: failed to map ashmem region!
>       gralloc_register_buffer(0x20a540): map failed: Out of memory
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.729 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   W/GraphicBufferMapper: importBuffer(0x20a4a0) failed: 2
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.729 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   E/GraphicBuffer: unflatten: registerBuffer failed: Unknown error -2
>   (2)
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.729 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung E/Surface:
>   dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: 2
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.729 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   E/EGL_emulation: tid 5070: init(382): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
>       tid 5070: eglCreateWindowSurface(922): error 0x3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.732 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung
>   A/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to create EGLSurface for window 0xbf1d4008,
>   eglErr = EGL_BAD_ALLOC
>
> 06-18 19:36:33.733 5041-5070/com.example.mainbuchhaltung A/libc: Fatal
>   signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5070 (RenderThread)

I think the problem is in the MemberInfo code, but I can't figure out the error. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: A member has an Id attached to him, so I want to get the ID and give it to the method open - then it should use the ID to get the member's information - the activity should be started and I should be able to see that member's information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening an activity using an "empty" intent in your MemberInfo activity `onCreate` method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("MemberID")) {
    long memberid = intent.getLongExtra("MemberID", -1);
    // TODO: get customer details based on customer id
    intent.putExtra("MemberID", memberid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.empty_not_saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Remove this from the onCreate:

```
        intent.putExtra("MemberID", memberid);
        startActivity(intent);
```

After you've launched the member info activity all you need to get the member id passed as an extra is:

```
long memberid = intent.getLongExtra("MemberID", -1);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Can I ask you another question? I set up a ClickListener for my list and it should give me the position of the member in the list with the method getAdapterPosition. For some reasons, when I start the activity, I only see the example I set up for the activity, but not the actual member. Is the method(getAdapterPosition) that I use wrong or what could be the reason that the position doesn't get passed?

Comment: That's probably due to the async nature of getAllMember(), it might not have had time to load the data

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling activity when member clicks

```
public void onMemberClick(int position) {
    Log.i("what", "gotpositionroger");
    Member member = mMember.get(position);
    Log.i("the", "aftergotpositionroger");
    
  Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MemberInfo.class);
  intent.putExtra("id",member.getId());
  startActivity(intent);
   }
```

And in Meminfoactivity you should do like

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra("MemberID")) {
    long memberid = intent.getLongExtra("MemberID", -1);
    
   // intent.putExtra("MemberID", memberid);
   //you cant able to start the activity without new Intent(thid,Example.class)
   // startActivity(intent);
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.empty_not_saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. In the first part of code, where you have intent.putExtras("id", member.getId());, it shows me this line underlined in red. It shows me: Cannot resolve method 'putExtras(java.lang.String, long)'.

Comment: it's 'putExtra'